# When I use Alert.Dialog the application crashes

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, builder

I want to show prograssbar with the help of Alert.Dialog while saving data to database. but after registration the program crashes.

A method that gives an error after running:

```
private void saveData() {

        if (isPickPhoto) {
            StorageReference mRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ShopList Images")
                    .child(imgUri.getLastPathSegment());
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddShopListActivity.this);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setView(R.layout.progress_layout);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

            mRef.putFile(imgUri).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!uriTask.isComplete()) ;
                Uri urlImage = uriTask.getResult();
                imageUrl = urlImage.toString();
                uploadData();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Yükleme yapmak için galeriden bir resim seç", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

but when I use it to update the data it works fine.

method that works flawlessly:

```
private void updateData() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddShopListActivity.this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setView(R.layout.progress_layout);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        if (isPhotoChanged) {

            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("ShopList Images").child(imgUri.getLastPathSegment());

            storageReference.putFile(imgUri).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!uriTask.isComplete()) ;
                Uri urlImage = uriTask.getResult();
                imageUrl = urlImage.toString();
                uploadData();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
        } else {
            imageUrl = oldImageUrl;
            uploadData();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

what can i do for using AlertDialog in saveData() metod ?

i want to show progressbar with Dialog.Alert.builder. but it crashes after data saved.

LogCat screen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MMb1.png)

Comment: Provide your logs or crash log here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular exception seems to be a bit tricky to interpret, but [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2850597/8143123) a good explanation of what can cause this error.
tl;dr: For your case the error appear to be the `dialog` is outliving the `Activity` it is called in, because the `.dismiss()`-call isn't being issued properly sometimes.

Now it seems to be a bit tricky to narrow down the root, when the cause of your `Activity` shutting down prematurely won't show up in the logs. (There are reports of observing that in the comments under a couple of the answers of the SO post above.)
So to find out what could be shutting down your method before the `dialog` could be dismissed, comment out the `dialog.show()`, reproduce the steps that caused this error to occur and check the logs again.

Comment: awesome. thanks for the answer. onSuccessListener lives longer than main algorithm. I changed .dismis() position their places to be before the finish. now all is working.

Answer (score 1):

The WindowLeaked error occurs when you try to show a dialog after the activity has finished. To fix this issue, use isFinishing() to check if the activity is still running before showing the dialog:

```
private void saveData() {
    if (isPickPhoto) {
        //...
        if (!AddShopListActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
            dialog.show();
        }

        mRef.putFile(imgUri).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
            //...
            if (!AddShopListActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            if (!AddShopListActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

This will prevent the crash by ensuring the dialog is only shown and dismissed when the activity is active.